# Show that $n\bmod m$ is periodic $\forall n,m \in \mathbb{N}^+$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, periodic-functions

How can I show that $n\bmod m$ is periodic?

If I have a simple example like $n\bmod6 \equiv a$ how can I show that this is periodic if e.g $f(n) = n\bmod6$?

Comment: What should be periodic, and in which sense? Do you mean $n\mod m=(n+k)\mod m$ for some period length $k$? Or perhaps $n\mod m=n^k\mod m$ for some period length $k$?

Comment: @String Good point.. I'll clarify that

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** A function $f$ is periodic with period $m$ if $f(n+m)=f(n)$ for all $n$.

Comment: Well, can I just simply say $(n+m)\,mod\,m = n\,mod\,m + \underbrace{m\,mod\,m}_{=0} = n\,mod\,m \,\square$? That would of course make sense :D